# Where can I motivate for Ubuntu support?

Tags: community

Occasionally I find projects with limited or no Ubuntu support. As an individual with limited time, I can't do much about it except log a ticket requesting Ubuntu support (or packaging, or Unity integration, etc). Often the response is that the development team don't have Ubuntu expertise.

Is there a *meaningful* location to log tickets/suggestions where Canonical / the Ubuntu community (people who share the motivation and wherewithall to investigate the issue) can see it?

My understanding is that:

- Logging Launchpad issues for *universe* packages is largely meaningless if the package maintainers/developers don't already use Launchpad.
- [Brainstorm didn't work out.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/ubuntu-brainstorm-to-get-the-boot) (which means the answer may be, "there is no such place")

Comment: Maybe a division of the community and/or Canonical which encourages and helps devs to support Ubuntu?

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu - hmmmm?

Comment: Which projects are you referring to? It can be possible to guess the dependencies needed to get it to work, though often scripts made by third parties for 'linux support' need fixing to work :)

Comment: @Wilf the question is not about a specific project(s) - it is based on a recurring issue I have experienced over many years

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/RFP?

Answer (score -2):

You know, it is actually Ubuntu's decision to build a custom DE that does not support the commonly accepted ways to create tray icons, notifications and stuff.
So it must be Ubuntu's task, not the application developer's one, to add a support for Unity to all applications that need it. So yes, the Launchpad. Don't annoy the application developers too much if, say, tray icon does not show up in Unity.

Comment: unity integration was just an example

Comment: assume I have already logged that ticket with the developer, now I want to log an inverse ticket with the ubuntu community (or something similar, it doesn't literally have to be a ticket)